# send email w/o gmail authentication in java

Tags: java, authentication, smtp, sendmail

Hi I have to send email in java.

The below has successfully worked for me.

```
          public class SendMail {

             public static void main(String[] args) {                   
                 Properties props = new Properties();
                 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                                   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                        return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxx@gmail.com","xxxxx!1");
                                     }
                                   });

                  try {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@gmail.com"));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                      InternetAddress.parse("mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com"));
                        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                                      "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");
                        Transport.send(message);
                        System.out.println("Done"); 
                      } catch (MessagingException e) {
                          throw new RuntimeException(e);
                      }
              }

           }
```

Here I have mentioned gmail username and password. But I have to send email without using username and password in my code. How can I develop this. Please help me.

Comment: the first thing I would do now is change my gmail password after posting it here!! For greater security also turn on 2 factor authentication.

Comment: Yes, you should always obfuscate sensitive data (company name, etc) when asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: off topic: you should not write an email to a spammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a mail.properties file and put username and password into in that file. Use Properties to retrieve data from this file in your code.

This link could be useful to load Properties object

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/loading-property-file

Comment: i doesn't mention my gmail username and password anywhere in my code.it is possible for send mail in java

Comment: you can sent email annonymously from any machine, need not be delivered in inbox.

Comment: no.i have delivery the mail in my inbox.but in my code below line i have mentioned username and password of my mailid.that line i doesn't mention username and password at the same time my mail is delivery on my mail inbox.any other possible way is available here. return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxx@gmail.com","xxxx!1");

Comment: @user1897014 - "i doesn't mention my gmail username and password anywhere in my code" Yes. Yes, you did. Read the code that you originally posted. Your email account has almost surely been compromised by now. What were you thinking?!

Comment: @JackManey probably OP doesnt know that SO tracks history of edits on the post!